# How to change URL without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Some websites like https://featurepoints.com are using a technique in which the user opens a new page without any kind of refresh, the URL will be changed but there is no refresh or an ajax usage.
What techniques are they using? Is it pushState?

Comment: Yes, they usually use `History.pushState` or the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) more generally. It is common functionality in single-page applications (SPAs).

Edit: Don't know why you tagged vue.js and jQuery, but the Vue Router supports using the History API: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: I removed the `jquery` and `vue.js` tags as they are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Thank you guys, then I will go for History.pushState. I was wondering how featurepoints runs fast.
@GalaxyCat105 yes I suppose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you might be looking for history.pushState

```
history.pushState([data], [title], [URL]);
```

Using your example of https://featurepoints.com/

```
history.pushState(null, 'FeaturePoints Login', 'https://featurepoints.com/login');
```

Source and more details https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/